# Javascript method chaining on slice not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice

I am trying to reorganize an array to use it in a for loop. 
I have tried slicing it then merging with sliced elements but i get the error

```
TypeError: images.slice(...).merge is not a function
```

Here is an example of what I am trying

```
var images = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var f_iamges = images.slice(2).merge(images.slice(0, 2))

console.log(f_iamges)
```

I expected output `["2", "3", "4", "5", "0", "1"]`
I also want the original copy to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `concat`:

```
images.slice(2).concat(images.slice(0, 2))
```